# Modifying the bounding rectangle in paperjs

Tags: paperjs

I am trying to modify the bounding rectangle of an object in paperjs. 
Here is my code:

```
project.currentStyle = {
    fillColor: 'green',
    strokeColor: 'black'
};

var circle = new Path.Circle(new Point(150, 150), 50);

var bounds = circle.bounds;
bounds.insert(2, new Point(bounds.center.x, bounds.top));
bounds.insert(2, new Point(bounds.center.x, bounds.top-25));
bounds.insert(2, new Point(bounds.center.x, bounds.top));
```

I am getting an error that `bounds.insert` is not a function.
If this is not possible, how can I add segments to the bounding rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the [`Path.Rectangle()`](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#path-rectangle-rectangle) method which create a rectangular `Path`, and a [`Rectangle`](http://paperjs.org/reference/rectangle/) which corresponds to the abstract geometric shape:

> A [`Rectangle`](http://paperjs.org/reference/rectangle/) specifies an area that is enclosed by it’s top-left point (x, y), its width, and its height. It should not be confused with a rectangular path, it is not an item.

You can easily create a `Path` from your circle bounds:

```
let rectanglePath = new Path.Rectangle(circle.bounds);
rectanglePath.strokeColor = 'red';
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there no way I can modify the bounds itself. I tried `circle.bounds = new Path.Rectangle(circle.bounds)`, but it didn't work. In my actual scenario, I will be having many shapes drawn, I will need to move them, resize them, rotate them, etc. If I use bounds o using hitTest, that would be simple. Otherwise, for each shape, I will need to maintain one more rectanglePath and select them on hitTest, which would be a bit complex.